# How to use transparent image as background on transparent winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, transparency

I have a WinForm in C#, I have both BackCOlor and TransparencyKey set to color "Lime". If I compile at this point the form is transparent. Then I added an BackgroundImage with a Lime background (#00ff00), but the Lime on the image is not transparent.

How can I get the background image to have a transparent background too?

The image I used is a .bmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the Lime color in the picture is not identical to Lime you set as TransparencyKey.

Use ColorPicker: http://www.iconico.com/download.aspx?app=ColorPic&type=free

over your picture to see what color code the lime in the picture has: e.g. #XXXXXX.
Then put that number in TransparencyKey, don't just use "Lime".

Answer (score 0):

Use an image format that supports transparency such as PNG.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Are you sure that the BMP has exactly the same background color as your form, and that it has not been altered some way, perhaps by a reduction in the number of colors or something similar?